# how to create an ant task which dumps a mysql dump?

Tags: mysql, ant

I want to execute this command **mysql -u root -e "source F:\dump.sql"** How do i do this with the ant task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `exec` task in Ant.

here is the [reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) on how to use it